How to use this view in change my items, like this photo
enter image description here
How to use this view in change my items, like this photo.
is it library or recycler View?
I want a list of items or recycler like this photo.
help me, please!
How to use this view in change my items, like this photo.
is it library or recycler View?
I want a list of items or recycler like this photo.
help me, please!

This can be achieved in Android using various methods, including using libraries or custom implementations. Here are a few approaches you can consider:

Using ViewPager2 with a Transformer

Using RecyclerView with cover flow effects (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtXDhaqbTZQ) ( close to what you want )

Using Third-Party Libraries (https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#examples)



ممنونم علیرضا جان با کمکت مشکلم حل شد

خواهش میکنم. با آرزوی موفقیت برای شما
